# Can't find "record espresso test" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio-4.1, android-espresso-recorder

Android Studio version 4.1.2

I followed the android testing codelab direction "Choose Run > Record Espresso Test" but I didn't find it in the "Run" menu and can't find it elsewhere. Is it removed in this version of AS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out I didn't enable the test recorder plugin...

Answer (score 1):

To enable the test recorder if it is missing from your Android Studio,

1. Go to Settings.
2. Click on Plugins.
3. Search for "Test Recorder" under the Installed tab.
4. Enable "Test Recorder" by clicking the checkbox in the search result or "Enable" in the details screen.

[image: Searching For Test Recorder On Android Studio]